# Existence of an homeomorphic between [0,1] to X × Y

Tags: general-topology

I'm doing a practice exam questions and am stuck at this question:

> Are there topological spaces X,Y (each with more than one point), such that [0,1] is homeomorphic to X×Y? What if we replace [0,1] with R?

I'm not even sure how to start tackle it, any help and clues will be appreciated! My head is leading me to "cut-points" area, but I'm not sure abuot it./

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had the right idea. $X$ and $Y$ are the image under the projections of $X\times Y$, so they must be path connected.

Now on $[0,1]$ there are many points that after removing them make this space disconnected. Can this happen with $X\times Y$, assuming both have more than one point?

(**Hint**: make a picture and try to connect two arbitrary points with a path.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:** Prove that:

- If $X\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, then both $X$ and $Y$ are connected.
- If $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$, then $(X\times Y)\setminus\{(x_0,y_0)\}$ is still connected.